# CUDA NSight is not installed with CUDA 5.0 installation file on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, cuda, installation

As I see there is not a download link for Nsight Eclipse at Nvidia site, and it says it will be installed by the CUDA 5 installation natively. But it has been not installed with the CUDA installation. Is there any one who has also had this problem and is there any other external link to install Nsight Eclipse separately?

Comment: As far as i know, nsight eclipse edition is only available for linux and will be installed with the linux installation scripts. Under windows CUDA will install the nsight visual studio edition.

Comment: @Erogol: Please pay *much* more attention to the text of your questions. As you posted it, this question was a near unintelligible mess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as Nsight Eclipse edition for Windows.

On Windows platforms, Nsight is integrates with Visual Studio (and requires the Microsoft compilers). For Linux and OS X, Nvidia ships the Nsight Eclipse edition as a stand alone IDE running over the top of the native gcc based toolchains.

Comment: So much for hoping to avoid installing VS!