# is it possible to code CUDA at virtual box Win8?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, cuda, virtualbox

I know that by using virtual box, graphics card cannot be utilized by all the measures so I think it is not possible but I also think that coding cuda at least setting the CUDA developing environment is easier at Windows (unfortunately) thus if it is possible I plan to setup win8 to virtual box on my Ubuntu.

I do want to use win since I am at optimus Nvidia machine thus there is a driver problem at Ubuntu. In addition compilation of the code at Eclipse does not work due to that driver flaw. In case I use Win there might be the remedy of the problem.

Comment: Why not just use the native Linux CUDA SDK if you're running Ubuntu ?

Comment: As Paul R said, use the native [Linux CUDA SDK](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads). Just run the script and you will have a configured nsight eclipse edition - just what you wanted from your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644127/cuda-nsight-is-not-installed-with-cuda-5-0-installation-file-on-windows-8).

Answer (score 3):

1. Even if you get success in setting up environment in your virtual box to compile cuda code and you compiled cuda code there it will be of no use because you wont be able to run the code in virtual box.
2. Yes, your are absolutely right that installing drivers on optimus nvidia card is difficult task. I was also stuck with the same problem. but with release of cuda 5, installing cuda on Ubuntu is very simple.

follow these simple steps.

### Driver installation ##

1. Download cuda 5 from here.(32bit or 64bit depending on OS)

   > [Cuda 5 download](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)
2. Install required tools by following command

   > sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev build-essential libx11-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev libgl1-mesa-glx libglu1-mesa libglu1-mesa-dev
3. Next, blacklist the unnecessary modules

   > sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

   add following lines at last

   > blacklist vga16fb
   >
   > blacklist nouveau
   >
   > blacklist rivafb
   >
   > blacklist nvidiafb
   >
   > blacklist rivatv

   and reboot your system.
4. After reboot press Ctrl+Alt+F1. Login there and enter following command.

   > service lightdm stop
5. Go to location where you have downloaded cuda 5. In my case its on desktop.

   > cd Desktop
6. make it run from shell

   > chmod +x cuda_5.3.35_linux*****
7. Run from terminal

   > ./cuda_5.3.35_linux*****
8. accept it, when asked to install drivers press y and n for cudatoolkit and gpucomputingsdk
9. now reboot and you are done with driver installation.
10. To install cudatoolkit and gpucomputingsdk follow this link

### [Cuda 4.2 installation on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Cuda)